# Redirecting to external link using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mern

I want to add button property which will redirect to external link when it is clicked. prop which should be added to button is `siteURL` .Button should be in class = "project-item-details-container". Do I have to install any external package?

sample button:  Visit site

code which I have written -

```
  const ProjectItem = props => {
  const {projectDetails} = props
  const {projectId, imageURL, description, title, siteURL} = projectDetails
  return (
    <>
      <li className="project-item-container">
        <img
          className="project-item-image"
          src={imageURL}
          alt={`project-item${projectId}`}
        />
        <div className="project-item-details-container">
          <h1 className="project-item-title">{title}</h1>
          <p className="project-item-description">{description}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this.
I have used attribute in button element.

```
const ProjectItem = props => {
  const {projectDetails} = props
  const {projectId, imageURL, description, title, siteURL} = projectDetails
  return (
    <>
      <li className="project-item-container">
        <img
          className="project-item-image"
          src={imageURL}
          alt={`project-item${projectId}`}
        />
        <div className="project-item-details-container">
          <h1 className="project-item-title">{title}</h1>
          <p className="project-item-description">{description}</p>
          <button type="button" className="project-redirect-button">
            <a href={siteURL} alt="Broken Link">
              Visit Site
            </a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const ProjectItem = props => {
  const {projectDetails} = props
  const {projectId, imageURL, description, title, siteURL} = projectDetails
  return (
    <>
      <li className="project-item-container">
        <img
          className="project-item-image"
          src={imageURL}
          alt={`project-item${projectId}`}
        />
        <div className="project-item-details-container">
          <h1 className="project-item-title">{title}</h1>
          <p className="project-item-description">{description}</p>
        </div>
        <a href={siteUrl}>{title}</a>
      </li>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: then replace `a` with `button` put an `onClick` or you can style `a` as `button`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
 const ProjectItem = props => {
  const {projectDetails} = props
  const {projectId, imageURL, description, title, siteURL} = projectDetails
  return (
    <>
      <li className="project-item-container">
        <img
          className="project-item-image"
          src={imageURL}
          alt={`project-item${projectId}`}
        />
        <div className="project-item-details-container">
          <h1 className="project-item-title">{title}</h1>
          <p className="project-item-description">{description}</p>
          <button onClick={()=>window.location.href=siteURL}>{title}</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  )
}
```